# Using Rsync to read variable from text file but include wild cards in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, rsync

i am trying to RSync files from a folder, however i would like to define a subset of these files.
I have created a text file with the wildcard names but i get a "no such file" error.

below is my source directory file list, the names will always be there, but the date/time will change so i am using the *wildcard to grab file.

```
20200207-COE-2020-02-06T2332238.SCH
20200207-SMXH-2020-02-06T23140696.SCH
20200207-SMXH alias-2020-02-06T23140766.SCH
20200128-SARE-2020-01-28T15202081.SCH
20200128-SARH alias-2020-01-28T15161179.SCH
```

my source list - i tried by entering the wild character in this and in the rsync command line

```
*SMXH*
*COE*
*SMXH\ alias*
```

my rsync command

```
rsync -tv --files-from=/var/tmp/red_badger/bus_names.txt "foo@bar:/apps/schedules/archived/" /var/tmp/red_badger/files --dry-run
```

error message

```
receiving file list ... rsync: link_stat "/apps/schedules/archived/*SMXH*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/apps/schedules/archived/*COE*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/apps/archived/*SMXH\ alias*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

using the wild card works in one line command

```
 rsync -tv "foo@bar:/apps/schedules/archived/*SMXH\ alias*" .
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--files-from` option is for specifying exact filename matches. To use patterns instead of actual file names, use the `--include-from` option instead.

Comment: i used  ``` rsync -tv --include-from="/var/tmp/Steve/bus_names.txt" --exclude-from="*" "foo@bar:/apps/schedules/archived/" /var/tmp/Steve/files --dry-run
``` and got ```rsync: failed to open exclude file *: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1058) [client=3.0.9] ``` when using include exclude and ```skipping directory /apps/schedules/archived/.``` when just using include-from.

Comment: @Red_badger if you are not specifying a file for excludes, you want `--exclude` not `--exclude-from`.